# Shopify API - 822 error registering webhook

Tags: php, shopify

Hi I am trying to register a Shopify webhook like so

```php
    /**
     * @param $webHook
     * @return array
     */
    public function registerWebHook($webHook)
    {
        try {
            $request = $this->request('admin/webhooks.json', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'webhook' => [
                        'topic' => $webHook,
                        'address' => trim(config('app.url'), '/') . '/webhooks',
                        'format' => 'json'
                    ]
                ]
            ], 'post');
        } catch(BadResponseException $e) {
            dd($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
        }

        return $this->parseResponseBody($request);
    }
```

The underlying code sets the access token headers and so on which all works fine with every other request, its just this one that returns the following error;

```
{"error":"822: unexpected token at 'webhook%5Btopic%5D=products%2Fupdate\u0026webhook%5Baddress%5D=https%3A%2F%2F51t7e3cb.ngrok.io%2Fwebhooks\u0026webhook%5Bformat%5D=json'"}
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

```php
    /**
     * @param string $endpoint
     * @param array $payload
     * @param string $method
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
     */
    public function request($endpoint = '', $payload = [], $method = 'get')
    {
        $payload['headers'] = [
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token' => session()->get('access_data')['access_token'],
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ];

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $url = sprintf(
            'https://%s/%s',
            env('SHOPIFY_SHOP_DOMAIN'),
            $endpoint
        );

        $response = $client->{$method}($url, $payload);
        if($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `$this->request`? Is that something from a Shopify PHP SDK, some other HTTP request method of some framework, or …?

Comment: its my underlying code which uses guzzle, ill edit now

Comment: Is `admin/webhooks.json` the right endpoint URL here? According to https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/webhook it should be `/admin/api/#{api_version}/webhooks.json`

Comment: I believe 'admin/...' uses the latest api version.

Comment: Are you sure? I don’t see that mentioned under https://help.shopify.com/en/api/versioning

Comment: 99% sure, tried with `admin/api/2020-10/webhooks.json` and same error

Comment: From the docs: `If your request doesn't include a version, then the API also defaults to the oldest supported stable version.`

Comment: You say you are sending `application/json` via the request header, but are you actually? Shouldn’t `form_params` be `json` instead then? http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json

Comment: that seems to haver done it! stick it as an answer and I'll accept it mate

Comment: Okay, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are sending `application/json` via the request header, but using the `form_params` key in your payload array causes the data to be formatted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

This should use the `json` key in that place instead, so that guzzle knows you want this to be encoded as JSON in the request body. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json